# Can not pull docker images when switched to linux containers with error "Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers" behind proxy

Tags: docker, proxy

I want to run simple **docker run hello-world** command in Windows machine. I can run the command without error while in Windows container.

However, I need to run some Linux specific images but when I switched to **Linux Containers** and tried to run same command, it gives following error:

[image]

I checked the Internet but I have found nothing for specifically Linux Container. I am working behind corporate proxy and I set proxy settings like this:

[image]

I also changed network settings to use manual 8.8.8.8 DNS: (I tried by not setting manual DNS but error did not change.)

[image]

What may cause Linux containers to not pull docker images? Thanks for any help.